# Opencv cannot find chess board corners

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have the following image taken from the LMS fisheye dataset:

https://www.lms.tf.fau.eu/research/downloads/fisheye-data-set/

[image]

However, on finding corners in open cv with all possible pattern sizes like so:

```
for i in range(3,22*22):
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (i,i), cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH)
    print(i, ret, corners)
```

I get False None for each pattern size from 3,3 to 22*22, 22*22. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So coincidence that this week's practical class, my tutor let us play the coding that is similar to what you ask. I'm new in python and I don't know much in openCV. Hope that the coding can give you an idea.

```
filename = 'Test.png'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
cv2.imshow('picOriChessboard',img)

# Corner detection using Harris corner detector
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None) #result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255] # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
cv2.imshow('picCornerHarris', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Testing : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NzxW.png

Comment: It's detecting multiple points for each edge, not a single point, as needed.

Comment: I think you can filter all the point that has close x and y and remain one for each edge.